# Why doesn't the author subtract everything by two first before applying modulus?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

This is from a youtube video on the Chinese Remainder Theorem  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ru7mWZJlRQg

[image]

What the author has done thus far is basically 
1.Make sure that the mods, 3, 4, 5 are relatively pairwise prime by showing that gcd(3,4) = 1, gcd(3,5) = 1 and gcd(4,5) = 1.

2.Set up a table with mod 3, mod 4, mod 5 as the columns. He multiplied one column by the other two so that when applied it's modulus, say for mod 3, mod 4 and mod 5 column values will be set to zero.
3.Here's the part that I have a question about. The author states that the first linear congruence 
x $\equiv$ 2(mod 3) must be satisfied and to do so, he mods all the values by 3. The only non zero value will be the value in column 1(because of the last step).

My question is by the definition of  a is congruent to b modulo m(below)
[image]

Shouldn't the author have to subtract all the values by 2 first and then mod 3, that way he get 18 mod 3, 13 mod 3, and 9 mod 3, or 0, 1, and 0? Is there a reason he doesn't have to do this? To me, this isn't consistent with the definition of congruency

Comment: Are you saying that $x=20mod3$ is the set of solutions to all three equations?

Comment: ${\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ 15\equiv 0 \equiv 12\,\Rightarrow\, n+15+12\equiv n\,$ by the Congruence Sum Rule. The point is, that by construction, all the other columns are $\equiv 0\pmod 3.\ $

Comment: Not me, its the video. What he first did to satisfy the first congruence, x ≡ 2 mod( 3) , was to apply mod 3 to all three columns. He was left with 20, 0, 0, meaning x = 20 mod (3) or x$\equiv$ 20 mod(3) which is equivalent to x $\equiv$ 2 mod (3)

Comment: @BillDubuque At the bottom of that snippet, shouldn't it be  x≡ 20 mod(3), not  x = 20 mod (3)? I don't think by definition, they mean the same thing?

Comment: $\,x\equiv 20\equiv 2\pmod3\,$ so it is a solution of the first congruence, as claimed.

Comment: @BillDubuque I get that but notation wise, the author uses x= 20 mod 3, not x$\equiv$ 20 mod (3)? The first is just a modular expression and the second would be a congruence?

Comment: @committedandroider through an abuse of notation, people often use $=$ and $\equiv$ interchangeably in casual contexts.  It is a bad habit, but so long as it is understood from context, its forgivable.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh ok thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @BillDubuque Because all of the numbers have the same congruence (mod 3), is that why the Congruence Sum Rule works? So 20(mod3) +15(mod3) + 12(mod3) = 2(mod3) + 0 + 0 = 2(mod 3)?

Comment: @com Your photo doesn't show $\, x = 20\ {\rm mod}\ 3.\,$ It shows $\,x\equiv 20\pmod{3},\,$ i.e. $\,3\mid x-20,\,$  To apply the Congruence Sum Rule to multiple summands you can either do one summand at a time, or prove the n-ary extension of the Sum Rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First that's not the only definition there is of congruence. For example you may define it as :

> Two integers $a$ and $b$ are said to be *congruents modulo m* if the remainders of the division of $a$ and $b$ by $m$ are equal.

Which is equivalent to your definition, and for some more intuitive.

Second, notice that [congruence is an equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation)  and also we may sum and multiply through congruence.

Third you may represent a residue class by

$$ \overline {a} = \{x \in \mathbb Z ; x \equiv a \mod m\} $$

and the basic properties of arithmetic you are used to with the integers is also valid here. With this in mind we may "apply" congruence modulo $3$ to obtain

$$\overline{x} = \overline {20 + 15 + 12} = \overline {20} + \overline {15} + \overline {12} = \overline {2} + \overline {0} + \overline {0}$$

Because according to definition we gave here $$20 = 6 \cdot 3 + \color{#f05}2\ ,\  15 = 5 \cdot 3 + \color{#f05}0\ ,\  12 = 4 \cdot 3 + \color{#f05}0\ \ \text{and}\ \  2 = 0 \cdot 3 + \color{#f05}2$$

In order words, $$ x \equiv 20 \equiv 2 \mod 3$$

Also you may notice that, of course,

$$(20 -2)  \equiv 0 \mod 3$$

Because $$18 = 6 \cdot 3 + \color{#f05} 0$$

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Is a residue class the same as a set? I noticed that you used set builder notation.

Comment: Yes it is, think of $\mathbb Z_2 = \{\overline{0}, \overline{1}\}$. The subset $\overline{1}$ for instance, is the one that contains all odd numbers.

Comment: SO because congruence is an equivalence relation, you are basically summing $\equiv$20mod(3) + $\equiv$15mod(3) + $\equiv$12mod(3) and getting $\equiv$2mod(3) as the final answer?

Comment: That's right!..